# Why use django-south?

Tags: django, django-south

As far as I understand, django-south is pretty much like version control for your database schema. But why exactly is it better than python manage.py syncdb when developing? I can understand if you've actually launched and can't afford to just delete the database, but I don't see the point in using it when you can just delete the database.

Comment: Deleting the database is not an option when you are developing something already used somewhere else. In this case you need to have some kind of migration between older version and newer version. `syncdb` does not support migrations, but South does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purpose is to migrate schemas in a production environment. If your running a production app with tons of data gathered from your users and you want to then expand a table, it would be really unfortunate to have to delete the database and lose all the data.

The benefit it adds during development is that is removes the time you would have to waste dropping a database, re-syncing the database and creating a new super admin every time you make a change to your models.

Comment: Also, you can roll back to a specific migration, easily have it do actions before and after the migration, etc...

Comment: Now I'm sold on it, thanks :) Will it also change the code in models.py or will I have to do that myself?

Comment: No it will not change the code in models.py, you use south after you change models.py in order to make sure your database correctly reflects your models without having to drop your database.